# HTTP connection error in Android 11 : cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project that upload an image from user's phone to HTTP server and return it.
I'm trying to use POST method, but I keep get this error message.

I already did this but nothing changed.
cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"

Here is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
private void uploadImage(byte[] imageBytes){

            Log.d("1","1");

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT,ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS))
                    .build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(DjangoApi.DJANGO_SITE)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();


            DjangoApi postApi= retrofit.create(DjangoApi.class);
            Log.d("2","retrofit 생성");

            RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(imageBytes,MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"));
            Log.d("3", "requestBody 생성");

            MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","image.jpg",requestBody);

            Log.d("이미지 확인"," ");

            Call<RequestBody> call = postApi.uploadFile(fileToUpload);
            Log.d("call","call");

            call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, retrofit2.Response<RequestBody> response) {
                    if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.e("연결이 비정상적 : ", "error code : " + response.code());
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.d("good", "good");

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("fail", t.toString());
                    //Log.d("fail", "fail");
                }
            });

            Log.d("end","end");

    }
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.saveyourfingerprint"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_main"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SaveYourFingerprint">

        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
D/fail: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8000
```

Plus, I cannot downgrade Sandbox to 1

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending it to the right spot.  127.0.0.1 is localhost.  You're trying to send it to the phone itself.  Fix your DJANGO_URL.

Since you fell into this mistake, here's what your next one will be-  if you're developing this on your home PC (which seems likely), make sure the android device is on the same WIFI network and you've set up your router to allow traffic between devices on the network and that PC and port.  Otherwise your router will block it.  And don't expect it to work when you're away from home, because there's 0 chance you have a public IP without a firewall in front of it.